# How to get images attached to the shared posts using facebook graph api

Tags: ruby-on-rails, facebook, facebook-graph-api

I am using Facebook graph API  `posts` endpoint to display users Facebook posts, i am passing `fields=picture` to get the image related to each post.

From the posts endpoint response i encountered a shared post by the user(user shared one of her friends image post ), The `picture node` of this post contains the

> Image URL of display photo(DP) of the original post Facebook user

Instead of the image she shared.

In order to get the shared image i tried passing all other fields such as 
`child_attachments`, `attachments`, But i am unable to get the shared post image URL.

Is there any way to get the image URLs of a page using Facebook graph API endpoints?

Comment: Just because a friend shared my post, does not mean your app has any access to my photos ...

Comment: so u are saying we won't be able to access shared posts images and videos ?

Comment: Only if your app has the necessary permission to access those in the first place ... and for user posts and user photos, that means the owner would have to grant your app permission first.

Comment: A shared video is something different than a video uploaded by a user.

Comment: i am passing field `source` to get the attached/shared(video from another user post) video link by the user, and i am getting all these video link(added/shared)

Comment: Did the other user _upload_ a video, or did they just share a link that have a video embedded via OG meta tags?